# In Python, using freetype, how do I obtain the descent line for a given font size?

Tags: python, freetype

This code gives me a value of -434. I'm not sure what font size this is assuming, but it's obviously a very large one. How would I obtain this value, assuming a font size of 20 points? I suspect the correct value would be somewhere around -4. Performance is not an issue, because I will not be putting it inside of a loop.

```
import freetype as ft
face = ft.Face("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf")
desc = face.descender
print(desc)
```

Comment: I think TTF is based on a standard coordinate system, where 1000 is the nominal height of a character, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I found a great [article from Microsoft (TrueType Fundamentals)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/ttch01) explaining TrueType, but it implies that the measurement system is arbitrary.

Comment: If I subtract the descent from the ascent, and multiply the result by 20/1000, I get a height of 45.76, which doesn't seem plausible. If instead of 1000, I use 2048, I get 22.34, which is at least plausible, but I'm not sure if it's really correct. I would actually prefer to do this without any calculation, by changing the font size and then measuring it, so I can see what's really happening, rather than what I think should happen.